# Setting autoComplete List Items Vertically

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

My Auto complete List comes Horizontally Like this :

[image]

But I want to display List Items Vertically

I have search and try to implement some solutions like this :

1. Overflow Feature

   ```
   .ui-autocomplete {
   max-height: 600px;
   overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
   overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
   z-index:1000 !important;
   ```

   }

--

2.

Setting position attribute :

```
   .ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
    position:absolute;
}
```

---

But they are not working ..

This is my complete Code ..

```
<div>            
@Html.TextBox("Country")
</div>


<div id="menu-container" style="position:absolute; width: 200px;"></div>
```

---

```
  $("#Country").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "*Controller Data*",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);

                        }
                    })
            },
            appendTo: '#menu-container',
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                }
            });
```

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think you can accomplish this with only css ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jpeh2acb/))

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
  width: auto !important;
}
.ui-menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```